# Maintaining list structure when duplicating

Tags: scheme, racket

I am writing a function to duplicate all the items in a list, so that a list like (a (b c)) becomes (a a (b b c c)), however my function returns (a a b b c c). How do I ensure I retain the internal list structure? Here is my current code:

```
(define double
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((null? l) '())
          ((list? l) (append (double (car l)) (double (cdr l))))
          (else (append (list l) (list l)) )
    )
))
```

Comment: If it "duplicates all the items in a list" shouldn't it return `(a a (b c) (b c))`?

Comment: perhaps I didn't word it as best I could, but I want it to duplicate each item in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the structure of the list, you have to avoid using `append`. Here is an implementation:

```
(define (double lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) empty]
    [(list? (car lst))
     (cons (double (car lst))
           (double (cdr lst)))]
    [else
     (cons (car lst) (cons (car lst)
           (double (cdr lst))))]))
```

For example,

```
> (double '(a (b c) ((a b) (c d))))
'(a a (b b c c) ((a a b b) (c c d d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Shallow copy:

```
(define (copy-list lst)
  (map values lst))
```

And of course `map` is like this for one list argument:

```
(define (map f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (f (car lst))
            (map f (cdr lst)))))
```

Deep copy:

```
(define (copy-tree tree)
  (accumulate-tree tree values cons '()))
```

And this is how `accumulate-tree` is made:

```
(define (accumulate-tree tree term combiner null-value)
  (let rec ((tree tree))
    (cond ((null? tree) null-value)
          ((not (pair? tree)) (term tree))
          (else (combiner (rec (car tree)) 
                          (rec (cdr tree)))))))
```